# Using Gson Deserializer for a List

Tags: android, json, deserialization, gson, json-deserialization

I'm using Gson and need a lot of personal deserializer. From my server I'm getting 2 Lists, which should directly save in a List. This is my gsonBuilder:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Book.class, new BookDeserializer());
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new ImageDeserializer());
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Image.class, new ImageDeserializer());
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(boolean.class, new BooleanDeserializer());
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class, new BooleanDeserializer());
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

The Book.class and my Image.class implemented as a list in my object. I have a deserializer, which response me a list. BUT: He doesn't call the BookDeserializer!!!
First he doesn't call any list-deserializer. But after adding this line

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new ImageDeserializer());
```

he calls the image-deserializer and it works. But he won't call it for the Book.class. I tried to add these line:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new BookDeserializer());
```

But nothing happens. I think this is, because i already add a typeadapter for List.class. But how can I say, that he have to use 2 different?
Thanks for help :)

EDIT:
I think I should say, that I have a List of own objects in my object :)